# How can I batch convert photos made from some angle to frontal view?

Tags: batch, perspective

Is there an application that would batch convert photos made from some angle to frontal ones? I know [ShiftN](http://www.shiftn.de/ShiftN_functionality.html) does batch perspective correction, but I would like to automatically convert some photos of buildings that have visible lines and were made from like 70' angle to frontal textures.

Comment: Why does the batch perspective correction not work for your needs?  Also, keep in mind that the actual captured information is still going to look weird unless the building is perfectly flat as you are actually capturing the image at an angle which means that any 3d geometry will cause odd stretching in the corrected image.

Comment: I know it won't be perfect, but I need it anyway. Perspective correction did not work because the angle is horizontal not vertical. Rotating 90' did not help, because it is not about perspective. Those tools only correct keystone effect. I can't show exact photos because I dont have them, but found really nice sample: a shopping shelf - like in here: http://www.shelving-supermarket.com/photo/pl448718-heavy_duty_chrome_powder_coat_shelving_supermarket_shop_shelf_racks_display.jpg

Comment: Perspective correction can be performed in any direction and will work on the sample image you showed.  Lightroom 5 has an automatic "upright" tool which may be useful to speed up the process, but it doesn't always get it right.

Comment: Ok I know why it does not work. It does with the photo in comment. But my angle is like 2 times bigger :/

Comment: @FlashThunder What's your application?  For photography, with an angle even greater than in your sample photo, a fully perspective corrected version is going to look *very* weird.  If the application is more like google street view (and you have a huge number of images), perhaps you can try to roll your own algorithm (using a package like Mathematica/MATLAB) and you'll find more expertise on dsp.stackexchange.com.  You'd be starting with a Hough transform to detect lines.

Comment: Do you mean a 70 minute or a 70 degree angle?  70 degrees is huge.

Comment: -1 for no sample image. The process clearly works with most images and as it stands the question is for everyone not reproducible. Upvote once sample is added...

Answer (score 1):

**What you want is generally not possible** because there is no image information for the part of the subject hidden from view. For instance, in a side-view portrait, half of the subject's face is turned away from the camera.